# I get the problem in python 3.9 : " serial' has no attribue 'Serial' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, pyserial, python-3.9

i'm learning python. And in a serial stuff :

```
serial_port = serial.Serial(port = "COM3", baudrate = 9600)
```

i get the "attribute serial" error

"module serial has no attribute 'Serial'

i tried every current solutions we can find on internet. i uninstalled serial library and installed pyserial, updated libraries, changed my project files name etc. but nothing changes

i'm currently using a 3.9 python version and pyserial is 3.5 version.

what else can i do to fix this problem ?

Comment: Where did you get the example?

Comment: here but it's in French : https://arduino.developpez.com/tutoriels/physique-computationnelle/?page=le-couple-arduino-moins-python#L3-4-2

Comment: could it be that you installed [serial](https://pypi.org/project/serial/) (a JSON serializer) instead of [pyserial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial.html) (the serial communications library)?

Comment: quite the opposite, i uninstalled serial and installed pyserial (last version, 3.5)

Comment: Did you create a file named `serial.py`? Or you used "serial" in some weird way (`serial = sys`) There are many possibilities, and you wrote very little about it (and you didn't include not full code)

Comment: ok, so how are you importing it? could you post the part of the code where you import the library?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki <import serial>

Comment: and for precision i use python 3.

Comment: update : i realized that i get this error only on Visual Studio code. here's the test i made : i typed my command lines (there's only 3) on the python3 console. Then i tried on the python3 console on visual studio. i get the error on the VS code console only. knowing that it comes from the same directory in my PC.

Comment: now i run the file directly from the python3 shell and i get the first error code "serial has no attribute Serial"

Comment: `<import serial>` is incorrect python code. you need to remove the angle brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solve the problem, simply by uninstalling and re-installing Python directly on my computer. something were probably wrong after an update, i don't know.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).